# Preventing Users with the Customer Portal Manager Custom profile from seeing Contact and User records from other Users in their Account

Tags: customer-portal

I'm beginning a project where I will have users with the "Customer Portal Manager Custom" license using my Customer Portal.  I've noticed that these users are automatically granted read access to the Contact and User records of people who are in the same account that they are.  I do not want this functionality.  What are my options to restrict access so that these portal users can only see their own Contact and User records?

The only thing I can think of is to create separate account records for each contact and I'd rather not do that.

Comment: For contact you can make the Org Wide Default for contacts as private which solves the problem of users gaining access to others record.What is the problem if the user access another users record unless you have some critical information like salary or numbers very specific to the user !!!

Comment: For portals, even setting Org Wide Default for contacts to private will not solve this problem.  Sharing rules are inserted for contacts from the same account so that they can see each other's contact records.  In my use case, there are many unrelated contacts using the portal, so sharing names and contact information among users would be a problem.